# in java, When "DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary" use this function, the expected result is different

Tags: java, base64

The following code , It is Java code that is encoded as sha1 and then encoded as base64.

```
System.out.println("key : "+DatatypeConverter
                                .printBase64Binary(MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest(("wZCYQre/AdRckTa9/hwEHg==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11")
                                        .getBytes("UTF-8"))));
```

above code result is..

```
key : 1jBpw9uqcRx3Cl/AajHQmeDYw/c=
```

but The results from sha1-encoded websites and base64-encoded websites is

```
key : ZDYzMDY5YzNkYmFhNzExYzc3MGE1ZmMwNmEzMWQwOTllMGQ4YzNmNw==
```

Why are the results of the two different?

Comment: The second string is too long to be a SHA-1 hash. It could be the base-64–encoded result of two SHA-1 hashes concatenated. Remove inaccurate information and describe clearly the process used to obtain the second string, if that's the focus of your question. Ask a single question in each post; encoding a hash in C is a separate question.

Comment: The second string result is from www.sha1-online.com and https://www.base64decode.org
As you said, I only have one question.
Why are the results of the two different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the websites, you are base-64–encoding the hash after encoding in hexadecimal characters. This is strange and probably not what you want. Your Java code is directly base-64–encoding the hash itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I got a hint.And thank you for giving me advice on how to ask questions.